# How to press Ctrl + b + capital I (trying to install plugins in tmux)?

Tags: tmux

Everywhere they say  Press
`ctrl + b + I (capital I)`
to fetch the plugin.

What does that mean? Is it like `ctrl + b + shift + i`  or `ctrl + b + capslock(on) + i` 
(capital I)
or maybe my terminal is broken(I don't know)? What is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it's a sequence of two keystrokes, one after the other rather than simultaneously:  `ctrl + b` then `shift + i`.

[This cheat sheet](https://gist.github.com/scottjwood/9067d332f2933a0c0c0e) lists a number of Tmux keystroke combinations, and all of them are Ctrl+b followed by one or more keystrokes.  The one you're asking about isn't on that sheet, but I don't think Tmux will work differently for your keystroke than it works for the others.

Comment: "I don't think Tmux will work differently" -- Agree. But even if it wanted to work differently, it couldn't. The terminal sends nothing when you press and hold `Ctrl` (or `Shift`), it sends a character denoted `^B` when you additionally press `b` (respectively: `I` when you additionally press `i`). Tmux (like any application designed to work with a tty) has access to incoming bytes (interpreted as characters one by one or sometimes as sequences), not directly to keystrokes. There is no standard sequence for `Ctrl+Shift+b` nor `Ctrl+Shift+i` nor `Ctrl+Shift+b+i`.

Comment: It was helpful. Thank you.